# Open source projects using Wix source files to learn from

Tags: wix

I have to write an installer and want to use Wix. The documentation on the website is not working and I like learning by example. Does someone know an open source project with good WiX source files, preferable for Wix version 3.0 or 3.5.

Comment: If anyone does answer this, I'd love to see a good complex WIX project if possible :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) is one of the bigger ones that I know that uses WiX.  I also have a project called [IsWiX](http://iswix.codeplex.com) that sits on top of WiX to author Merge Modules.   IsWiX uses WiX/IsWiX itself to do it's own installer so there are some examples there.  Finally there is a new WiX book out that you might want to purchase and read through.

[WiX: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513724)

Answer (score 3):

TortoiseSVN uses WiX and there is a blog outlining some issue they had.

**Edit**: [TortoiseSVN Blog: On Major Upgrade Problems with WiX](http://tortoisesvn.net/majorupgrade.html)

Comment: I can't put links in comments but just Google for "TortoiseSVN" and "Tortisesvn blog".

Answer (score 2):

A few Codeplex projects that use Wix:

- [Wix](http://wix.codeplex.com/), of course
- [SytleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)
- [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.codeplex.com/)
- [VisualHg](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a open source WIX Sample projects available here, which were very helpful in getting me started.

And don't forget to check out the Powerpoint slide(s) in the slides folder.
I found it really valuable in getting me started with WiX compared to the Wix Tutorial on the Wix website or the Packtpub books.

https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples